# Transforming Set of Columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame that consists of countries, and counts under dates like so:

```
country | 1/2 | 1/3
   A    |  5  |  7
   B    |  4  |  6
```

Is there a way to gather these dates onto one column while also keep the counts for each date and from which particular country? More specifically, can I get it to look like the following:

```
country | date | count
   A    |  1/2 |   5
   A    |  1/3 |   7
   B    |  1/2 |   4
   B    |  1/3 |   6
```

Comment: you should look into the function "melt"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df=df.melt(id_vars="country", var_name="date", value_name="count")
```

Outputs:

```py
  country date  count
0       A  1/2      5
1       B  1/2      4
2       A  1/3      7
3       B  1/3      6
```

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know such a function existed.